# question about the future tense

Tags: modal-verbs, future, will-be-going

In a sentence like

> How do you get to the train station?

What would be an appropriate answer (tense wise)? Could you say both of these two:

> - I’ll drive you.
> - I’m going to drive you.

I think both could be correct: the *will* one if you say it right after you’ve asked the question, and the *going to* one if it’s planned and you’re having that chat a week before or something.

Comment: You might want to read [this tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/will-be-going/info).  English most commonly uses two different ways of putting a verb into the periphrastic future tense, one with a modal and one with a finite form of *to be going to*, and while these are usually interchangeable, there is some nuance between them.  Or can be.

Comment: Seems to me that the question should be "How do **I** get to the train station?", which can mean one of two things: "Can you tell me how to get to (give me directions to) the train station?" or "How will I get to (what mode of transportation will I use to travel to) the train station?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I'll drive you there" is the normal way this kind offer would be made in response to a mere request for information.

"I'm going to drive you there" is either patronising, forceful, or adding the connotation that this was the plan before 'you' asked the question.

Comment: thanks alot ! sometimes the english language can be quite confusing :o)

Comment: I had to stop and run this through my head to convince myself that you were on to something here, but I think you actually might be.  However, it is devilishly subtle, contextually dependent, and in speech at least might well require a bit of phrasal prosody to get it across. Which means one could also intone it in a way where that was *not* the implication. Hm.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine in either situation. The *tendency* in US conversation is to match your interlocutor's form, thus:

> How will I get to the train station? ... I'll drive you.
>   How am I going to get to the train station? ... I'm going to drive you.
>   How am I getting to the train station? ... I'm driving you.

Both of these *tend* to arise when planning. *How do I get to the train station* or *How do you get to the train station* (this would the impersonal *you*) will *tend* to arise when you're asking how to get there *right now* or very shortly. In this case the answer will *tend* to be

> I can drive you.

Note that I've used *tend* and emphasized it throughout. None of this is even remotely a "rule" - just somewhat more likely than alternatives.

Comment: There were so many of these will-vs-be-going questions that I finally made a  [tag:will-be-going] tag and [a tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/will-be-going/info) for them. Please feel free to hack on it to include stuff I didn’t manage to wedge in there. Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist  Cool. I added futurive non-pasts; I thought about adding the corresponding emphatic forms, but ya gotta stop somewhere.

Comment: People use existing tenses for all kinds of nuances that aren’t always clear from their conjugations. “Tomorrow I get my teeth cleaned.” uses the present to mean the future. Spanish “Eso será Juan” (That will be John) actually expresses probability, like that must/might be John or that’s probably John, even though it is in the inflectional future indicative, not some fancier aspect. I guess we do that in English, too: “That will/would be John” uses future or conditional, but means, well, something else.

Comment: @tchrist "He'll be in San Francisco now, but he's in Albuquerque tomorrow, and I think he was going to be in Dallas on Friday."